# How to generate md5_hex() in php?

Tags: php, md5

I need to connect to an API.

I Need to send parameters in encryption form of `md5_hex()`.

it seems, its used in pearl. php couldn't recognize it.

is there any way to convert `md5` to `md5_hex()`?

or generate `md5_hex()` in php?

**ADDITION : URL to hit**

```
https://fm.transfer-to.com/cgi-bin/shop/topup?login=login&key=1&md5=2f922ef79253f93d0fc05d0ac0b0d100&action=ping

login = login
key=1
token = pass99
md5=md5_hex(login.token.key);
```

Comment: Pretty sure `md5` = `md5_hex`. There is a flag in `md5` that allows you to generate binary data instead, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[md5()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) in PHP already returns in hex (32 characters 0-9/a-f).

If you use second parameter of md5() as `TRUE` in PHP to get the 'true' md5 binary value which consist of 16 bits. In your case, you don't need this second parameter to get a hex result.

Comment: it returs this, when second parameter is true.md5=?^Cb…As1É&½œ‰±. and still it shows, wrong md5 encoding

Comment: @Shuhail, do not use the second argument.